# UUID Path Bindable - Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

In my build.sbt I have

```
routesImport += "play.api.mvc.PathBindable.bindableUUID"
```

And in my routes I have:

```
GET      /groups/:id     controllers.GroupController.get(id)
```

And in my controller I have

```
class GroupController { ....

   def get (id: UUID)
```

I am getting the following error for the above route

```
type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: java.util.UUID
```

How can used uuid in path in routes file in Play. I am using play 2.4.2 - scala 2.11.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

String is the default type for parameters in the routes file. To change this, you need to explicitly specify a type for the Id:

```
GET      /groups/:id     controllers.GroupController.get(id: java.util.UUID)
```

If you do that, you should find you can also delete the import of `bindableUUID` in your build file.